# I cannot set activeStyle correctly on a <NavLink>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot set properly the `NavLink` using `activeStyle` when my url is on `map`.

Basically when I click `NavLink` I can navigate to the correct route, but only `<NavLink to='/'` is being marked as active.

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
const NavigationList = ({ navigations, onNavigationClick }) => (
  <div>
    <NavLink to='/' activeStyle={{
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'red'
    }}>
     Home
    </NavLink >
    <br />
    <NavLink to='map' activeStyle={{
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'red'
    }}>
      Map
    </NavLink >
  </div>
)
```

In my router configuration I have:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Forecast from './Forecast'
import Map from './Map'

const Root = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Forecast} />
        <Route exact path='/map' component={Map} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
)
export default Root
```

Comment: Have you tried to change `to='/map'` with an additional slash `/` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mismatch between `NavLink.to` and your `Route.path`.

Try the following:

```
const NavigationList = ({ navigations, onNavigationClick }) => (
  <div>
    <NavLink to='/' activeStyle={{
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'red'
    }}>
     Home
    </NavLink >
    <br />
    <NavLink to='/map' activeStyle={{
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'red'
    }}>
      Map
    </NavLink >
  </div>
)
```